# Can't get my Aside element to format properly

Tags: html, css, formatting, format

I am unable to get my aside element to align properly with the rest of my page. It sits above the main element and spills into the header. How do I fix that?

Here's what it looks like on the page:

[image]

Here's the CSS Style code I'm using:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:darkseagreen;
}

header {
    padding: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text: white;
    background-color: #4EEE94;
}

aside {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0.5%;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
    background-color: #1C86EE;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

#main {
    width: 446px;
    margin-right: 27%;
    padding: 0.5%;
    background-color: #EE6363;
    text: white;
position: relative;
border-radius: 4%;
}

.map {
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 3em auto 3em auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 95%;


.image {
    padding: 5%;
    margin: 4em;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 15px;
}
}

div {
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

nav ul li {
    margin-right: 1em;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav li a {
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: underline;
 }

    footer {
    margin: 0.5% 27% 0 0;
    border-top: solid thick teal;
    padding: 0.5%;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML as well?

Comment: Here's the HTML for the aside element:

Comment: <aside>
<h2></h2>

<section id = "#history">
<article> 
<h3>History</h3>

<p> 
<a</a>

</p>
</article>
</section>

<section id = "#wildlife">
  
<article> 
<h3></h3>

<p></p>
<p></p>
</article>
</section>


<section id = "#geology">
 
<article>  
<h3></h3>
<p></p>
</article>
</section>

<section id = "#facts"> 
 
<article>  
<h3></h3>

<p>
 <blockquote>
</p>
</article>

</section>

<section id = "#more facts">
<article> 
<h3></h3>
<p> </p>
<p></p>
</article>

</section>

</aside>

Comment: I'm afraid we will need more than just the aside. To understand why it's flowing into your other elements, we'll need to see the implementation.

Comment: <section id = "#main">
 
<section id = "top">  
<h1>Welcome to Acadia National Park</h1>
</section> 

<section> 
 <div> 
 <h2>Map</h2>
 
 
    <p>
     <img class = "map" src="FPImages/MDI Map 2.png" alt="map of Mount Desert Island" style="width:auto";"height:auto;" usemap= "#MDImap"/>
    </p>
    
    <p>

     <map name ="MDImap">
      <area name ="Bar Harbor" shape="rect"
      coords="626,288,714,333"
      href="MDIcities.htm#Bar"
      alt="Bar Harbor" title="Bar Harbor" />"
      <area name ="Seal Harbor" shape="rect"
      coords="573,538,663,588"

Comment: href="MDIcities.htm#Seal"
      alt="Seal Harbor" title="Seal Harbor" />"
      <area name ="Northeast Harbor" shape="rect"
      coords="453,525,568,570"
      href="MDIcities.htm#NEH"
      alt="Southwest Harbor" title="Southwest Harbor" />"

Comment: <area name ="Southwest Harbor" shape="rect"
      coords="264,641,391,690"
      href="MDIcities.htm#SWH"
      alt="Somesville" title="Somesville" />"
      <area name ="Somesville" shape="rect"
      coords="244,319,366,354"
      href="MDIcities.htm#Somesville"
      alt="Somesville" title="Somesville" />"
      <area name ="Trenton" shape="rect"
      coords="160,36,265,69"
      href="MDIcities.htm#Trenton"
      alt="Trenton" title="Trenton" />"
      
      
     <area shape="default" href="MDIcities.htm" />
      </map>
    </p>
  
</div>
</section>

<div> 
<article>  
 <br/>
 <br/>

Comment: <section id = "start">
  
<h2> Start Here  </h2>
<p> For visitors looking for more adventure, there are campgrounds available for rent. <a href=" http://www.acadiamagic.com/acadia-lodging/camping.html">More Info</a> </p>
<p> For additional information on Acadia National Park, follow this link to the park's website:  <a href=" http://www.nps.gov/acad/index.htm ">More Info</a></p>
<p> Bus tours are also available <a href=" http://www.acadiatours.com/">More Info</a> </p>
</article>

Comment: </section><!-- end start section -->
</div>

<div>
<section id ="todo"> 
<h2>Things to Do</h2>
<p> Visitors to Acadia National Park can expect to activities such as: </p> 
             
<ul>
 <li><a href="http://www.barharborwhales.com/">Whale Watching</a> </li>   
 <li><a href="http://www.acadiafishingtours.com/">Deep Sea Fishing</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.nps.gov/acad/planyourvisit/hiking.htm">Hiking</a></li> 
 <li><a href="http://www.nps.gov/acad/planyourvisit/fishing.htm">Freshwater Fishing</a></li>

Comment: <li><a href="http://www.mansellboatrentals.com/">Sailing</a></li> 
 <li><a href="http://www.acadia.ws/sand-beach.htm">Swimming</a></li>
 <li><a href="http://www.nps.gov/acad/planyourvisit/picnicking.htm">Picnicking</a></li> 
</ul>         

 <p> There are 57 miles of carriage roads around the island, free from motor traffic, for hiking and biking. </p>

Comment: </p>
</section><!-- end todo section -->
</div>


<div>
<section id = "photo">
 <h2>Photo Gallery</h2>

<p>In the bay outside the town of Bar Harbor is an island called <strong>Bar Island</strong> which is accessible by a natural sandbar that appears daily during low tides

<p><img class = "image" src="FPImages/BarIsland.jpg" alt="Bar Island" style="width:304px;height:228px;" title="Bar Island"/></p>
 
 
<section id = "pine">
<p>Alongside Bar Island is a series of islands known as the <strong>Porcupine islands</strong>. 
</p>

Comment: <p><img class = "image" src="FPImages/PorcupineIslands.jpg" alt="Porcupine Islands Island" style="width:304px;height:228px;" title="Porcupine Islands"/></p>


<p><strong>Blueberries</strong> are in abundance on Mount Desert Island</p> 
<p><img class = "image" src="FPImages/Blueberry.jpg" alt="Blueberry" style="width:304px";"height:228px";></p>

</section><!-- end photo section -->
 </div>



<section id = "video"> 

<div> 
<article>
 <h2>Multimedia</h2>

Comment: <p>Below is a link to a youtube video which provides a brief visual overview of Acadia National Park.</p>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQTA8HU07zc">Acadia National Park visitor video</a> 

</section><!-- end video section -->

</div>

<div> 
<section id = "mustsee"> 
 
 <h2>Attractions</h2>

Comment: <p>Across the island, there are many must-see attractions. Some are located inside the park borders and require visitors to pay to access. Others are located outside the park and are free or pay-per attractions.
Complimentary bus service, known as the Island Explorer, provides visitors with easy access to all of Acadia's points of interest.

Comment: <ol>                                                                                                                                                            
    <li>Thunderhole - inside park</li>                                                                                      
    <li>Jordan Pond House - outside park</li>                                                                                      
    <li>Sand Beach - inside park</li>

Comment: <li>Bass Harbor Lighthouse - outside park</li>                                                                   
    <li>Carriage Roads - mixed in and outside of park</li>                                                                                          
  </ol>
</p>
</article>

</div>

<a href = "#top">Top of Page</a>

</section> <!-- end mustsee section -->
</section> <!-- end main column -->

Answer (score 0):

first issue with your css remove the braces after **.image** class.

```
.image {
padding: 5%;
margin: 4em;
float: left;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 15px;
}
}
```

second thing use **px** or **%** or **em** do not use all (recommended) .

Third use id something like this

```
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

Not `<div id="#xyz"></div>` # is the css selector

also do not use multiple id like `<div id="abc xyz"></div>` u cannot use multiple id's use class instead of `<div class="abc xyz"></div>`

Comment: So you're saying replace all the "id" with "class"?

Comment: if you want same CSS so u have to use class instead of ID

Comment: Read More about it

Short details : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp
More Details : https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/